# $\left | \int_{\mathbb R^d} \nabla f \nabla g \right| \leq \|\Delta f \|_{L^2} \|g\|_{L^{2}}$?

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $f, g \in L^{2}$ with $\nabla f, \nabla g \in L^2$

> Question: Can we expect
>
> $\left | \int_{\mathbb R^d}  \nabla f \nabla g \right| \leq \|\Delta f \|_{L^2} \|g\|_{L^{2}}$?

(Do I need to assume that $f$ or $g$ is smooth with compact support?)

My try:  I think,I should use [Cauchy-Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), but before this how I should transfer the  $\nabla$ of $g$ to $\Delta$ of $f$?

Comment: Recall the adjoint of the gradient is the negative of the divergence operator. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171556/gradient-operator-the-adjoint-of-minus-divergence-operator for details.

Then you have $\langle \nabla f,\nabla g\rangle = \langle \Delta f, g\rangle$ and the rest is easy.

Comment: Integrating by parts and use the fact that $L^p$ functions vanish at infinity ($C^{\infty}_0$ being dense in it).